# I want to know the meaning of 'OP?'

Tags: discussion

What is 'OP'? I want to know the meaning of 'OP' used here?

Comment: Instead of asking a new question you could have posted a comment under any of the recent questions you posted, and asked there. For some reason Stack Exchange forbids users to use Korean or Chinese characters in comments. I have tried copying and pasting your username, but it's impossible to post a comment. The system blocks me.

Comment: There are far more meanings for OP, the OP doesn't ask for a specific context. - further answering has been disabled - thus I am unable to answer.

Comment: @3kstc The OP is interested in knowing what it means on ELU. That's why it's been closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP stands for *Original Poster/Original Post*, which here is the person who asked the question or the question itself. In this case, it is you. In forums for instance, it is the person who starts the thread, or the first post in the thread.

> I agree with the OP, acronyms can be very useful.

In video games, however, OP means "overpowered" -  a person or group that is too powerful.

> That class is too OP, everyone is gonna play it!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that when i googled "op meaning", all of the top results explained this.  OP, please try google first for simple "What does X mean?" questions.